# Thévenin equivalent of a Norton equivalent

Tags: thevenin, homework, norton

A very simple question. When solving circuits, and you need to solve it using the mesh analysis, you want the circuit to only have voltage generators.I wonder if for an independent current generator like this one:

can it be transformed into this model

or this model?

And are the last two equivalent? Because some books use the first transformation while others use the second one.

Comment: Try plotting the I-V characteristics of your 3 circuits and you'll see if they're equivalent.

Comment: Why have you gone from zig-zag to box shaped resistors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.  Man, that was an easy one!

Yes, you can convert between Thevenin and Norton equivalents just as you show here.  Even the math in the drawings is right, leading me to think you cut them out of a textbook but doubted their accuracy and wanted to double check.  (Good job, BTW...in engineering, doubt is always your friend.)

The two Thevenin equivalents are themselves equivalent because, as it's a 2-terminal black box with no connection to the intermediate node, the order doesn't matter.  You don't care what the voltage is at the intermediate node.  In the Norton equivalent, there are only two nodes, both of which are exposed, so there's fewer alternatives...unless you want to count the poorly but somewhat accurately analogous one of drawing the current source to the right and the resistor to the left.

Comment: You totally got my point. Of course I knew the answer, but just because the maths where identical in both models. I just wanted a theoretical explanation as the one you provided since that is my weak point. Thank you good sir!